# Host Word application on Azure in a secure environment

Tags: azure, office365

I'm looking for information on hosting a Word application on Azure.  The goal is to allow customers to edit documents online in a secure portal with complete Word functionality, and prevent downloading or printing the document.  All the documentation / tutorials I have seen so far talk about creating an add-in for Word, or using an API for getting access to Office 365 files.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I realize this may be an unusual request but I don't know how else to state the objective.  If you're going to downvote then please give some advice on how to improve the question.

Comment: If users can edit documents, then they can copy content. Also, if they can view it then they can take photos too... Why is there a restriction to not allow downloading or printing?

Comment: The application is for translating sensitive documents from one language to another, and the client requires that the translator does not have a copy of the document on their local system.  You can't stop anyone from taking a picture of a screen, but I believe we can use Azure Rights Management to control download / print access etc to satisfy the client.

Comment: Professional translators use tools, like SDL Trados, to translate docx files. The tool would normally be installed on their local computer. If that's not going to be allowed, then they will have to install the tool on some remote system, so I'm even more confident that my answer is the only one what will meet all your requirements: The customer needs Azure VMs.

Answer (score 0):

To get everything you are asking for, including "complete" Word functionality, and prevent downloading and printing, I think you would have to get an Azure VM and install desktop Word (but no printers) on it. I'm not sure if (or how) you could keep users, who would have to have access to the VM, from downloading the Word files to their own machines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rick, but I don't think it would be scalable enough for what we need.